# Linked List print not working..?

Tags: c++

Building a linked list for the first time and I am not getting the expected output for some reason. I've searched other posts and drew it out but still can't find the problem. any insight is appreciated. I inserted 2 at the head and 7 at teh tail and when i call print in main, only 2 gets printed.

```
void List::print()
{
if (length == 0)
    cout << "The list is empty!" << endl;
else
{

Nodeptr temp = head; //temporary iterator

while (temp != NULL)
{
    cout << temp->data << " ";

    temp = temp->nextNode;
}

    cout << endl;
}
}


void List::insert_head(int data)
{
if (length == 0)
{
    head = new Node(data);
    tail = head;
}

else
{
    Nodeptr N = new Node(data); //create node by calling constructor

    N->nextNode = head; // set new nodes next to point to current head
    head = N; //make the head the new node
}

length++;
}

void List::insert_tail(int data)
{
if (length == 0)
{
    head = new Node(data);
    tail = head;
}
else
{
    Nodeptr N = new Node(data);

    N->nextNode = head;
    tail = N;

}

length++; //increase the list length
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should post definition of List and main aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you pointing your new node to head in insert_tail()? You need to link the last entry in the list to your new node.

You already have Node(2) present as both the head and tail, just add your Node(7) to the end:

```
Nodeptr N = new Node(data);
tail->nextNode = N;    
tail = N; // now head points to 2, tail points to 7
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as i analyze your code , I see the LL you have formed is

tail --> 7 --> 2 ->NULL

where Head is

head -> 2 -> NULL

you need to change insert_tail code as

tail->nextNode = N;

tail = N;

Now it is head -> 2 -> 7 -> NULL & tail -> 7 -> NULL

Hope it helps you !